# How to get class variable into module

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am unable to overwrite the module variable by class variable.

```
module Main
  class Traks
    @@endpoint ='/trakings'
    class << self
      include ViewTrait
    end
  end 
end
```

My Trait Module

```
module Main
  module ViewTrait
    def view(id:, options: "")
      Response::new("#{@@endpoint}/#{id}#{options}").resource(id: id).get
    end
  end
end
```

in ViewTrait I cannot access `@@endponint` which I have already defined in my Traks class. anyone can let me what I went wrong.

Comment: I can tell you that if you replace `@@` with single `@` this will work

Comment: @maxpleaner- I have tried but i am getting empty string in ViewTrait module.

Comment: Note that `class << self; include ViewTrait; end` is the same as `extend ViewTrait`.  See [Object#extend](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-extend).

Comment: @CarySwoveland- issue is accessing class variable into other module method.

Comment: isn't `@@endpoint` in the ViewTrait module is saying `self.@@endpoint` and in this case, wouldn't self be the ViewTrait module? If you call the correct receiver it should work?

Comment: Yes, I know. It's usual to invoke `include` on the singleton class rather than simply using `extend`, so I thought you might not know about `extend`.

Comment: Your question said "class instance variable", but `@@endpoint` (with two "at" signs) is a _"class variable"_ (I've changed that accordingly). A _"class **instance** variable"_ would be `@endpoint` (single "at" sign) in the scope of the class. You most likely want the latter anyway (or maybe a constant), because class variables have issues with inheritance.

Comment: @Stefan - I have fixed it.Thanks for joining the discussion. and I understand what you trying to say.

Comment: @ManishJ I just tested it and you answer _does_ work but so does replacing `@@` with `@` in your original code (using a class level instance variable not a class variable)

Comment: I'm not sure exactlly why but it seems class variables have some wierd behavior where you need to use `self.class_variable_get` in this case. Class-level instance variables behave more 'normally' which is why I advise them, and they do function the same for your purpose i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in ViewTrait I have replaced `@@endpoint` which `self.class_variable_get(:@@endpoint)` and I can access the class Variable into the module. hope this will help others.